# SAP HANA Procedure Dynamic SQL Select Into Variable: Not Working

Tags: sql, dynamic, geospatial, hana

Any ideas on how to use spatial functions in either a procedure or a calculation view? I cannot use a table function, as I need a cursor. Please see issues below:

I tried dynamic SQL in a stored procedure with select into (Doesn't allow into):
(About three months back it did work, but now cannot activate?)
This blog says it should work:
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/04/18/sap-hana-2.0-sps-01-new-developer-features-database-development/

**Dynamic SQL:**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NEW ST_Point(' || char(39) || 'POINT(' || decEndPointLong1 || ' ' || decEndPointLat1 || ')' || char(39) || ', 4326).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point(' || char(39) || 'POINT(' || CURRLONG || ' ' || CURRLAT || ')' || char(39) || ', 4326)) FROM DUMMY' INTO dDistEP1;
```

Then, I thought that I would create a calculation view,
This blog says it should work:
https://blogs.sap.com/2018/02/23/compute-distance-using-a-calculation-view-xs-advanced-model/

But, does not allow the use of spatial functions in ether columnengine or SQL engine.

**Calculated Column:**

[image: STPOINT Calculation View]

I went back and tried to re-activate the procedure that contains this code and has been working, and still works, but if I edit it and try to activate it has the same compile error. Cannot select into variable. So, something has changed since I first created this procedure.

Answer (score 0):

​Wow, I stumbled upon an alternate syntax that does not need single quotes:
​
https://blogs.sap.com/2017/02/17/transforming-spatial-data-in-sap-hana/

```
SELECT NEW ST_Point(-117.0400842, 32.92197086).ST_SRID(4326).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point(-117.0394467, 32.92241185).ST_SRID(4326)) FROM DUMMY
```

Now, I think that I can eliminate the Dynamic SQL.

**Looking at the two differ ways:**

```
1) SELECT NEW ST_Point(-117.0400842, 32.92197086).ST_SRID(4326).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point(-117.0394467, 32.92241185).ST_SRID(4326)) FROM DUMMY;
2) SELECT NEW ST_Point('POINT(-117.0400842 32.92197086)', 4326).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point('POINT(-117.0394467 32.92241185)', 4326)) FROM DUMMY;
```

They yield slightly different results (meters):

1. 77.06
2. 77.12

Probably, because (1) converts a calculated point to 4326, and (2) calculates the point based on 4326.

**So, this code:**

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT NEW ST_Point(' || char(39) || 'POINT(' || decEndPointLong1 || ' ' || decEndPointLat1 || ')' || char(39) || ', 4326).ST_Distance( NEW ST_Point(' || char(39) || 'POINT(' || CURRLONG || ' ' || CURRLAT || ')' || char(39) || ', 4326)) FROM DUMMY' INTO dDistEP1;
```

**​Boiled down to:**

```
SELECT r1.FROMLAT  INTO decEndPointLat1  FROM DUMMY;
SELECT r1.FROMLONG INTO decEndPointLong1 FROM DUMMY;
SELECT NEW ST_Point(decEndPointLong1, decEndPointLat1).ST_SRID(4326) INTO stEndCoord1 FROM DUMMY;
    
SELECT NEW ST_Point(CURRLONG, CURRLAT).ST_SRID(4326) INTO stCurrCoord FROM DUMMY;
    
SELECT stEndCoord1.ST_Distance(stCurrCoord) INTO dDistEP1 FROM DUMMY;
```

Comment: I don't understand what you were asking in the original question nor what you explain in your answer. What I can say is that all that `SELECT ... INTO ... FROM DUMMY` is not necessary and you could simply write assignments, e.g. `decEndPointLat1 := FROMLAT;`. No `DUMMY` required.